# GPS doesnt' work (Android web application)

Tags: android, web-applications, geolocation, gps

I'm writing web application for mobile phones and I need to use geolocation.

I wrote: (javascript)

```
function GeoLocationStart(){
    if(navigator.geolocation){
               navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess,onError);
            }
            else{
               alert("Functionality not available");
            }
}

function onSuccess(position) {
    var initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
    map.setCenter(initialLocation);
    var userMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: initialLocation,
          map: map,
          title: "You're here",
          icon: face
        });     
    userMarker.setMap(map);

    var userhtml = "It's you!";
    var UserInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: userhtml});   

    google.maps.event.addListener(userMarker, 'click', function() {     
            UserInfoWindow.open(map, userMarker);
          });
};

function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
```

It works fine but without GPS.

Though I set in Android manifest file permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

app doesn't start even searching sattelites. (Of course I checked GPS on my phone, it works in other applications)

How to switch GPS on?

Thanks

Comment: if you use Network provide i think it will work fine. If use GPS provider to find locations goto Settings->Location & Security and select Use GPS Satellite and uncheck use wireless networks.

Comment: I checked GPS in my phone settings and it works in other application but not in mine. I think wireless networks don't prevent GPS from working. Without them my application just stopped to show any location and GPS didn't appear

Comment: are you running your app near wifi?

Comment: no, 3G network. I think it doesn't matter: 3G or wifi, app doesn't search sattelite, it means that GPS doesn't launch. The problem is how to launch it

Comment: I added more JS code to my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

After location had found using wireless network, GPS stopped to work because the goal has been achieved - location is defined!

To continue searching position I wrote

```
var watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, { frequency: 3000 });
```

so GPS launched.

Comment: For future reference: `frequency` is not part of the W3C spec ([source](http://www.mosync.com/files/imports/doxygen/latest/html5/geolocation.options.md.html#geolocationOptions)), the property `maximumAge` does the same thing. (added this comment because google returns very few results for the `frequency` property.)